# Is a program's maximum stack size a constant value?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, aslr

I'm running on Linux version 5.0.0-29-generic, with a maximum stack size of 8192KBytes.
Is it always 8192 KBytes?

```
void main()
{
    char arr[8384000] = {};
    int x = 3;
}
```

I've run this code, and it only seg-faulted 50% of the time, I wonder why that is.

```
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/experiments (master) $ ./3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Overflowing the stack is undefined behaviour. So you cannot expect it to seg fault each time or even any other behaviour.

Comment: The stack size can vary a bit due to [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: The empty initializer (`{}`) is not valid C. Maybe you're using an extension, or a compiler for some other (C-like) language...

Comment: It's a compiler option, if that's what you mean.

Comment: It's clear what OP means. The stack is supposed to be such-a-size but it is not always that size. Sometimes the code gets stack overflow, sometimes does not. It has nothing to do with syntax errors.